# OS X - How to detect HDD activity?

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos

Is there any way (Objective-C or Swift API) for detecting HDD activity in OS X?

Comment: HDD activity happens even if no apps are running. You can check them with all running processes, if you are interested to check for a particular application.

Comment: `man opensnoop` might help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple's `fs_usage` uses `kdebug` tracing - [see its source code](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/system_cmds/system_cmds-496/fs_usage.tproj/fs_usage.c).

The book "Mac OS X Internals" has a whole chapter on the subject - [6.8.7 Fine-Grained Kernel Event Tracing (kdebug)](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=K8vUkpOXhN4C&pg=PA625#v=onepage&q&f=false).

I don't think this mechanism is exposed by Objective-C or Swift directly, but you can mix Objective-C code with C in `.mm` files, or [Interact with C APIs in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-XID_13).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer